# Webpack change window globale object scope

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-module-loader, es6-modules, jsencrypt

I am importing the npm module [JSEncrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) in my module to encrypt data. [JSEncrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) has window exported global object `window.Base64`.
 I am using webpack to bundle all modules. After bundling I run the code on the browser I can write on console `window.Base64` to get the value of this object.
 For security and compatibility reasons I would like to prevent that by changing `window.Base64` to local scope instead of window.
 Is that possible through webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the various options available for [shimming modules](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html), specifically the `exports-loader`.

This will bind the global to a module scope and it won't be overwriteable outside of Webpack's runtime.